# HBase wal getting bigger and bigger

Tags: hadoop, hbase

HBase wal getting bigger and bigger. The details are as follows:

```
3.2 K    9.6 K    /hbase/.hbase-snapshot
0        0        /hbase/.hbck
0        0        /hbase/.tmp
0        0        /hbase/MasterProcWALs
534.2 G  1.6 T    /hbase/WALs
400.3 M  1.2 G    /hbase/archive
0        0        /hbase/corrupt
267.0 G  796.5 G  /hbase/data
42       126      /hbase/hbase.id
7        21       /hbase/hbase.version
0        0        /hbase/mobdir
1.7 M    5.1 M    /hbase/oldWALs
0        0        /hbase/staging
```

HBase version 2.1.0. I set the following parameters:

```
hbase.master.logcleaner.ttl 60s
hbase.wal.regiongrouping.numgroups 2
hbase.regionserver.maxlogs 32
```

I calculated that my actual data size is equal to the size of the /hbase/data file directory. I tested to delete the log data which is relatively long, but the program will report an exception.

My data is mainly written by Phoenix. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: When I restart it.the log data is automatically deleted. but the new log generated can not be automatically cleaned up.What are the possible reasons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RegionServer logs, I found the following:
`2020-11-07 00:36:45,750 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AbstractFSWAL: Too many WALs; count=385, max=32; forcing flush of 10 regions(s): 12bcc8a5c4d5087f7c8607cc943250fc, 94fa37159fb219dd510d20eba243e5a3, b4c2ad111677e61758ada3af4c1e9dbb, d6c6928e0a400ce53c9d8ee614dc552c, d224956d3d3f6f7657d0e9c9c4c544cc, 02bda653c9a66d85b064c4070f3f9e9e, 9297d8fbbd3b535ac0807e3665517752, 5ffdd4261cb294a1922fdac8fbfeef2f, 27c13a71b1d90dc7640f7df2dfd2093b, 159931a1de7fab4a04cdc3bd967d77bc`

ah....
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-5250

Comment: Is there any solution to fix this issue ? My cluster meet this also. I am using hdp3.1.4,which has hbase2.0.2 and phoenix 5.0.0 .

Comment: At present. I used an self development extra program to clean up the log regularly.

Comment: I try hard to find out the appropriate way to clean WALs.Remove WALs using hdfs client  seems works,but bring in data loss.The hbase source code, WAL and AbstractFSWAL does not provide delete method. How can I clean WALs safely? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: When we restart HBase, this WALs will be cleaned up by HBase, so you can try to manually simulate some steps when restarting the service before clean WALs, such as manually flush the data and deleting it after completing these operations, which will not cause data loss. You can try to read the source code of this part, which will give you a good idea

Comment: I have carried out some related tests. When I manually clean up WALs, I should leave at least 3 hours WALs. In this case, it will not cause data loss. Of course, this is on the premise that I set an hour for WALs scrolling.